# How to return created instance in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, orm, sequelize.js

I'm testing sequelize for a new project, and I can't seem to be able to return my created instance, thanks for any help.

My create method :

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        "username" : req.body.username,
        "email"    : req.body.email,
        "pseudo"   : req.body.pseudo,
        "password" : bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10),
        "created_at" : sequelize.fn('NOW')
    };
   
    if (!user.username || !user.email) {
        res.status(201).send("username required!")
    }

    const newUser = async (user) => {
        await User.create(user)
        .then((data) => {return data;console.log(data);})
        .catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});}

    console.log(newUser); // this returns [AsyncFunction: newUser]
    res.status(200).send({"message" : "ok"});
    
}
```

And here's my model :

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../services/database_connection');
const validate = require('validator');

const User = sequelize.define('user',{
  id ,
  username ,
  email ,
  pseudo,
  password,
  created_at
}, {
  timestamps : false,
  freezeTableName : true,
});

module.exports = User;
```

How can i return my newUser instance after it's inserted in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create a function that will return `user` in Promise but you never call it.
Try next:

###### Promise

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        "username" : req.body.username,
        "email"    : req.body.email,
        "pseudo"   : req.body.pseudo,
        "password" : bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10),
        "created_at" : sequelize.fn('NOW')
    };
   
    if (!user.username || !user.email) {
        res.status(201).send("username required!")
    }

    User.create(user)
        .then((data) => { res.status(200).send(data)})
        .catch((e)=>{ console.log(e); res.status(500).end()});}        
}
```

###### OR with async/await

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        "username" : req.body.username,
        "email"    : req.body.email,
        "pseudo"   : req.body.pseudo,
        "password" : bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10),
        "created_at" : sequelize.fn('NOW')
    };
   
    if (!user.username || !user.email) {
        res.status(201).send("username required!")
    }

    const newUser = await User.create(user);
    res.status(200).send(newUser);
}
```

Comment: thank you the second solution worked best using async / await

Comment: @Majd so you can mark it as a correct answer )

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        "username": req.body.username,
        "email": req.body.email,
        "pseudo": req.body.pseudo,
        "password": bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
        "created_at": sequelize.fn('NOW')
    };

    if (!user.username || !user.email) {
        res.status(201).send("username required!")
    }

    User.create(user)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            res.status(200).send({ "message": "ok" });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            res.status(500).send({ "message": "Internal Server Error" });
        });

}
```

Do not use promises (`.then`) with async await.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).